# How to convert decimal point to comma in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression

I am working with data in Colombia where decimal points are written as commas. I would love to create a new column in QGIS that would convert all decimal points (periods) to commas for the purpose of labeling. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to create a new text column and replace points with commas. The function is `replace(original_string, find_text, replace_text)`; you'll need to convert the original number to a string, too. If you have a column LBL which is the number you want to use as a label:

1. Start editing the layer, open the attributes table and start the field calculator.
2. Select an output field name and make sure it's text.
3. In the 'Field calculator expression', paste the expression `replace(to string(LBL), '.', ',' )` and click `OK`.

For a longer term solution, you could probably change the region on your system too.

Answer (score 3):

in the attributes table 
past this expression :

```sql
replace("your column Name", ',', '.')
```

[image: How to convert decimal point to comma in QGIS?]