# Using relationship class to model multiple people buried in same grave for online cemetery application?

Tags: arcgis-online

I have to create an online application for a cemetery, just like this one:

http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=5676017d60ac44729e9cedf66709ff5e

Like in the example, in my case some tombs (only 3!) have more than one people burried, so there is an one-to-many relationship between the tombs and the occupants. So I’ve attached to the 400 polygons representing the tombs, the excel table containing all the people burried (403) using Make Query Table. And now I have 403 polygons, one for each occupant. I’ve exported the table into a shapefile because I had to save the table.

But is this the right way? If I put all these polygons into the online application, I guess that when I click on a tomb with two occupants, it will show me only one name, depending which one is above. And I won’t be happy with that.

Is creating a relationship class between the two tables more effective? I have’n done so far any online application or online map.

Comment: "Right" is relative and likely to be opinion-based or dependent on your online application. As an example, you've now got three plots in your data that have two polygons on top of each other. Go find them and click on them with the Identify tool. You'll see in the box that pops up it shows you *both* records. If your online app would do the same, you don't have a problem. You can do it this way or you could create a layer for just plots and a separate related table for persons in them, as long as your app supports that type of related query. Neither is 'right'.

Comment: It also depends on your online app interface (searching fields vs clicking map). This has actually been discussed here a few times. Take a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144480/ or  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131073/ I might even consider this a duplicate of the first one there. There are also some other questions related to this type of project here if you search on the terms 'grave' or 'cemetery' (overlapping but some different results returned).

Comment: It seems that related tables is a good option. ArcGIS online supports them http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/02/18/related-tables-exploring-new-ways-to-use-collector-for-arcgis/

Comment: This is how I want my application to look like: http://gis.dedham-ma.gov/cemeteryviewer_brookdale/ . To get something like this, I have to use Tax Parcel Viewer. I downloaded the pack from the ESRI site, but what I have to do next is another mystery for me.. I looked up if there is any topic about tax parcel viewer but found nothing.. Anyway.. I don't know if this app supports the overlapped polygons or the related tables.  But this is how my final work should look like. So if you could guide me how to start working with it, that could be very helpful. :)

Comment: That application is using the relate method (I think, see https://geonet.esri.com/thread/53697). They have one polygon for each 'lot' and one or more related 'grave records'. However I don't know the details behind how they're doing it on the web side backend.  (Scratch that, the [help page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/localgovernment/10.1/index.html#//028s0000000z000000) looks exactly like the app you link to).  I'm not familiar with it myself. The closest I can find to a tutorial is http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/03/19/configuring-the-arcgis-online-parcel-viewer-application/

Comment: one more question: for the same map, I also have to create some thematic maps. And for instance, if I represent the graves as polygons, and the occupants as points or with no geometry (all the occupants data into an excel table in the same geodatabase),  and then I relate the two tables, will I be able to make a symbology that would colour the polygons using a field from the related table? For me that looks impossible, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: From the comments above it sounds like you may have made some progress.  Consequently, can you take the opportunity to [edit] your question to revise it with a more focussed question about where you are now stuck, if that is the case, please?