# Changing Virtual field properties in QGis 3.0

Tags: qgis, length, precision, virtual-field

I have some existing virtual field with set Length and Precision

An example:

[image]

The formula was first set to rounding it by 2 digits
With the current settings it displays 10.00 instead of 10 because of the precision.

How do I change those two properties in the existing virtual field without deleting it and setting up a new one?

QGis displays numbers with points instead of commas.
For calculating with excel I do need commas.
A solution to this would also help a lot.

Comment: You can try in the expression `round($length,0)` to round the number to the whole number without digits.

Comment: That acts the same as round($length)
Still 10.00

Comment: Without having a new field with integer type, I think you cannot acheive what you want.

Comment: Sounds like I couldn't even change it to make it more precise if I wanted to.

Comment: no, you have to make a new virtual field and set it as integer if you do not want any digits

Comment: Ok and let's assume I want to have 3 digits instead of 2 now. how do i set the precision to 3?

Comment: um...if it is ultimately for label display, there is an option to format decimal places. (`Layer Properties | Labels | Formatting | Formatted numbers | Decimal places`)

Comment: You can get numbers with commas instead of decimal points by changing your locale (Settings > Options > Locale).

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about a **Virtual Field**, not a variable.

Comment: It's just for the attribute-table to calculate with it after exporting the data. yes it is a virtual field. do you mean changing the region in the local settings? i have changed it from german to english ad back and didn't have any changes. I also didn't found an option to change it elsewhere in the settings.

Comment: Based on the answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24619/how-to-convert-decimal-point-to-comma-in-qgis), I thought changing the region would switch from using decimal points to commas. It seems that's not the case. Maybe the other solution suggested for that question will help.